# Partition data.table into hash map of keys and records

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data table that looks like this

`````
````
KeyCol1 | KeyCol2 | DataCol1 | DataCol2 | DataCol3
--------|---------|----------|----------|---------
  1     |    2    |    a     |   b      |    c
  1     |    2    |    a     |   d      |    f
  1     |    3    |    e     |   h      |    i
  2     |    2    |   abc    |  hij     |   mno
````
`````

Is there any way to generate a hash map on a function of the two key columns that whose values would be the rows that match the keyed column?  For example, if the function of the keyed columns was `paste(KeyCol1,KeyCol2,sep=",")`, the hash map would give you:

`````
````>hash("1,2")
````

````KeyCol1 | KeyCol2 | DataCol1 | DataCol2 | DataCol3
--------|---------|----------|----------|---------
  1     |    2    |    a     |   b      |    c
  1     |    2    |    a     |   d      |    f
````
`````

Or is there another way that this can be done that I'm not thinking of.  The reason I would like to partition in this way is that the data.table I am working with is very large, and I would like to limit the amount of filtering done on the data table.  For example, I'd rather not do:
`tbl[KeyCol1==1&KeyCol2==2]`
and
`tbl[KeyCol1==1&&KeyCol2==3]`
separately, but rather I'd like the partition to take place once.  Right now, I just have a for loop doing:

`````
````filtered<-tbl[KeyCol1==1]
for (i in 2:3) {
    what_i_want<-filtered[KeyCol2==i]
    #do stuff
}
````
`````

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically the way the  `data.table` package works, so I don't see the point of going through all this yourself. How "big" is your data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering data.tables is blazingly fast.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
DT <- data.table(ID1 = sample(1:10, 1e7, replace=TRUE),
                 ID2 = sample(1:10, 1e7, replace=TRUE),
                 x   = rnorm(1e7),
                 y   = rpois(1e7, lambda=25))

setkey(DT, ID1, ID2)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(DT[J(1,3)], times=10)  # extract all rows where ID1==1 and ID2==3
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  DT[J(1, 3)] 4.383809 4.473238 4.526363 4.488933 4.563852 4.783576    10
```

So with a table containing 10 million rows, extracting all rows where `ID1==1` and `ID2==3` takes about 4.5ms. Is that not fast enough??

Comment: Ah yes, I'm new to R and data.tables and hadn't located that DT[J(1,3)] syntax.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For future reference, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) useful.